# Change permalink post_type=project in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Where can i change a permalink in post_type=project in wordpress?
I want to change from

**abc.com/project/test1**

to

**abc.com/gift/test1**

Answer (score 0):

If there i no option on your projects plugin or on "Settings" > "Permalink" you probably need to use a rewrite endpoint solution :
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/